# Filter in array of object inside object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, filter

I'm trying to filter some products with the categories (by the woocommerce API) but i have a little trouble to do it. do you have the right way to do it? thanks

**My array from the API :**

```js
{id: 199, name: "Dark Suit", slug: "dark-suit", permalink: "https://caisse.diliko.fr/produit/dark-suit/", date_created: "2020-08-20T10:53:06", …}
categories: Array(2)
0:
id: 30
name: "Clothing"
slug: "clothing"
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 31, name: "Men's Clothing", slug: "mens-clothing"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**And my filter function:**

```js
export const getProductsById = (products, id) => (
  
    products.filter(product => product.categories.name == id)
    );
```

Comment: your arrary from api doesnt look like an array. it looks like an object with categories being array but no content known

Comment: i believe you have expanded the category field, but is your products an array?

Comment: This question is at risk of being closed for being unclear. The reason is that the text in the first code snippet isn't actually javascript, but seems to be a copy/paste from a browser's console. It would be worth editing the question to make the first block real js code

Comment: yes the code was expanded. But your answer Chris was perfect ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want, I reckon. A filter that checks whether any of the categories of the product has the id you're looking for.

```js
products = [
{
  id: 199,
  name: "Dark Suit",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 30,
      name: "Clothing",
      slug: "clothing"
    },
    {
      id: 31,
      name: "Suits",
      slug: "suits"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 200,
  name: "Light Suit",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 30,
      name: "Clothing",
      slug: "clothing"
    },
    {
      id: 31,
      name: "Suits",
      slug: "suits"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 201,
  name: "Banana",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Fruit",
      slug: "fruit"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Yellow",
      slug: "yellow"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 201,
  name: "Orange",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Fruit",
      slug: "fruit"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Orange",
      slug: "orange"
    }
  ]
}

];

console.log(filter(31)); //suits
console.log(filter(2)); // fruit
console.log(filter(3)); // yellow

function filter(categoryId) {
  return products.filter(product=>product.categories.some(element=>element.id==categoryId));
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly what i want and with your code, it's perfect thank so much.

The final snippet : 

    products.filter(product=>product.categories.some(element=>element.name==id))

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more filter/iteration on  `products.category` because it is an array.

`products.filter(product => product.category.filter(category => category.name === id`

Comment: There are several products, each with several categories, as far as I can tell